# Convergence of recursive series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given $$u_1 \in \Bbb R, u_{n+1} = \frac 1 n e^{-u_n},$$ find if $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k$$ diverges or converges (conditional/absolute).

I tried:

Ratio test:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}   \left|{u_{n+1} \over u_n}\right| = \lim_{n\to \infty} {n-1 \over n} e^{u_{n-1} - u_n}$$

$$u_{n-1} - u_n = u_{n-1} - {1 \over n} e^{-u_{n-1}} = u_{n-1} - {1 \over {n e^{u_{n-1}}}} .$$ Dead end.

Root test:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n] u_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n] {1 \over n-1} e^{-u_{n-1}} = 1 \cdot\lim_{n \to \infty} {1 \over {e^{u_{n-1} \over n}}}$$

$${{u_{n-1} \over n}} = {{{1 \over n} e^{-u_{n-2}} \over n}}$$ ...stuck

Direct comparison? Can't think of a function to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that $u_n > 0$ for all $n \ge 1 $. Also $e^{-x}< 1$  for all $x>0$ therefore each $\displaystyle u_{n+1} < \frac 1 n$ and $\displaystyle u_{n+1} > \frac 1 n e^{-\frac 1 {n-1}} $.

As $n\to\infty$, $\displaystyle \frac 1 n e^{-\frac 1 {n-1}} \approx \frac 1 n$ due to which (by integral test) I think the series diverges. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Limit comparison test gives the answer directly in the last step. thank you :)